# Do health insurance premiums go up as you age?

Tags: canada, health-insurance

If I buy private health insurance at the age of 40, and start off with a monthly contribution of 200$ (for example), then does the amount of premium change when I reach 50? Since at 50, my medical expenses will probably be higher than at 40.

Does it depend on how much of my insurance limit I use in the 10 years between ages 40 and 50?

Does the answer change based on whether the insurance is through my employer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does depend on the details of your insurance. If you get insurance as a member of a group, eg at work, that is generally written based on the risk to the group as a whole and doesn't differ from individual to individual within that group. If you get it as an individual, you may be judged on your own risk though there are plans which effectively charge you more earlier so they can charge you less later.

I don't know which approach the health insurance exchanges use. Theoretically that's a large enough population to ve treated statistically as a group...